# Detect : from curl or browser

Tags: php, curl

I've got an almost empty page that I need for a curl.
The thing is that it is also accessible by a browser and looks weird.

Is it possible in PHP to detect if the request come from a browser or a curl ? So that way I can make a redirect if it comes from browser.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you the client Agent, among other stuff. If your curl does not pretend to be something else, it should do.

```
foreach (getallheaders() as $name => $value) {
    echo "$name: $value\n";
}
```

or simpler:
    $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']

gets you the user-agent (browser signatur) directly.

Comment: works by checking if `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` exist. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Browser sends `User-Agent` header in request, if you don't setup `User-Agent` in curl just check request for this header.